# c# best way to detect time of some action

Tags: c#, datetime

I tried to do the following:

```
    public class TimerTest
    {
        private DateTime start;

        public TimerTest()
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public TimerTest(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: " + message);
        }

        public void Finish(string message)
        {
            var time = DateTime.Now - start;

            var timeWent = String.Format("{0}.{1} sec.", time.Seconds, time.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));
```

but looks like this is wrong way...

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Based on your code I'd expect that output.

Comment: Could you write what you think the output should be?

Comment: Do note that that is a *terrible* way to do performance metrics, use `Stopwatch` instead.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have sufficient precision to measure differences in time this small.

Comment: @Servy: I'm surprised that he's seeing differences if 1ms.  I thought the timer resolution was several ms.

Comment: @EricJ. He's not using a `Timer`.

Comment: @PeterRasmussen as I wrote this code work time is less than 0.2 seconds! But not 480 seconds as you see in result

Comment: @Servy  in another place this code is work very well! But as separated class its not work.

Comment: @Servy: Just curious at what precision `DateTime` can be measured to? I did a [quick test here](http://ideone.com/t0iwo2).

Comment: @l'L'l It's going to be system dependent, so you cannot rely on a particular precision much at all.

Comment: Note that you should be using `TotalSeconds` instead of `Seconds`.  Otherwise if the difference is more than a minute you are truncating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe part of the problem is that you're not instantiating a new start time for every call, so you're just recording the difference from when that time was instantiated.

If you really want to get an accurate reading on the time it takes for code to execute, one of the better options is the Stopwatch class, described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: "so you're just recording the difference from when that time was instantiated." -- exactly this I need! Time difference between init of TimerTest and call of Finish() method. But results shown absolutely wrong.

Comment: Happy to hear that.  Remember to mark it as an answer if you believe I answered your question.

Comment: @Andrew can you please edit your question so it aligns with accepted answer. Otherwise it is hard to see how this post answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor overload

```
public TimerTest(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: " + message);
}
```

doesn't even initialize the time variable.  Did you mean for this constructor to be...

```
public TimerTest(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG: " + message);
    start = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: This coupled with the fact that the OP is using `TimeSpan.Seconds` instead of `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` explains the results.

Comment: yew! So this was my fault! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep.  As long as the OP doesn't try to time something longer than a minute.  Really System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch is the way to go, as maniak said.  Reinventing the wheel here.